# Authoritative Source on Sleep Requirement

Tags: sleep, aging

What is the hours of sleep required for someone over 70.

My Dads Dr (Internal Medicine) said at least 5 hours, yet Internet sites say 7 to 8.

Which Internet site is authoritative source for sleep requirements based on age?